# How to use Opencv to subsample a matrix by columns

Tags: c++, opencv

Using OpenCV and C++, I would like to sample a Matrix at every 0th, 3rd, 6th,9th.... column. What would be the fastest (or most elegant) way to do this?

For example, in Matlab this would be:

```
 sample = frame(:, 1:3:end);
```

In C++, I could do it as follows (but was wondering if there was a better way):

```
for(int i = 0; i < frame.cols/3;  i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < frame.rows; j++)
       sample.at<uchar>(j,i) = frame.at<uchar>(j,3*i);
```

Thanks

Comment: do you still need the original matrix? there are a couple of elegant ways to do that. in OpenCV you have row-major representation, so I'm not sure how to fix that, but imagine moving next column pointer to the next column you're interested in. 
`0-pointer -> (3*0)-pointer`
`1-pointer -> (3*1)-pointer`
`2-pointer -> (3*2)-pointer`
`...`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < frame.cols/3;  i++)
    frame.col(3*i).copyTo(sample.col(i));
```

That will do the job too.